# Using wildcard catchall to redirect misspelled subdomains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, wildcard

I have setup x.domain.com as a catchall for misspelled subdomains on my server. For instance, I want partners.domain.com to rewrite to partner.domain.com. I am having a difficult time figuring out how to make all of these rewrite rules. I believe my brain doesn't properly think in .htaccess, but what I simply want to say is "if the url is partners.domain.com, rewrite to partner.domain.com". I probably have about 20 or so of these rules to make, for different misspellings that have no specific pattern (and for many different subdomain).

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to make one of these for each mispelling:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^partners.domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://partner.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

add a "QSA" in the square brackets in the RewriteRule line if you want to redirect and preserve any GET query parameters: `[R=301,L,QSA]`